# How to set end time of local notifications of Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to push local notifications reminder to users based on the time they set, like someone wants a daily notification start from next Monday and ends two weeks after that. I only see two inputs of start time and repeat style of Notification of Expo, may I know how to end the notification based on the end time user provided? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is when they open the push notification, you check the current date and compare it to the 'expiration date' that you set when creating the notification (maybe save it in local storage or db). If so, call :

```
Notifications.cancelScheduledNotificationAsync(localNotificationId)
```

Refer to expo's documentation on how to attach data to your notifications.

Hope this helps

[Expo Local Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#notificationspresentlocalnotificationasynclocalnotification)

Comment: If you rely on the user tapping on the notification to run your code, you run the risk that they will never tap on it and the code will never run.  Unfortunately, I don't have a better solution as I am searching for a solution to a similar problem. But this is a known potential gotcha.